# How do i find out what error is causing my Android application to crash?

Tags: android, http, dom

I'm creating an application that's making a http request to a XML site. I'm then using DOM to get the information from XML. Problem is that the app is crashing when i try to run it in android emulator but it works perfectly when i run it as an java app. How can i find out what error is causing my android application to crash? I've enabled the permission to use internet.

I think this is the error from LogCat im getting:

```
11-15 11:57:37.618: WARN/dalvikvm(280): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-15 11:57:37.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 11:57:37.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {xml.android.test/xml.android.test.AndroidXMLActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
11-15 11:57:37.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2629)
11-15 11:57:37.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-15 11:57:37.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-15 11:57:37.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-15 11:57:37.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-15 11:57:37.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-15 11:57:37.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-15 11:57:37.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 11:57:37.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-15 11:57:37.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-15 11:57:37.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-15 11:57:37.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-15 11:57:37.702: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity xml.android.test/.AndroidXMLActivity
11-15 11:57:38.220: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44ed8770 xml.android.test/.AndroidXMLActivity}
11-15 11:57:38.228: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: 27460 ms (total 27460 ms)
11-15 11:57:48.303: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44ed8770 xml.android.test/.AndroidXMLActivity}
```

Comment: you can see the exception in logcat.

Comment: If you run the application if connected to pc you shoud get the exception message in LogCat, maybe with hint where to search in the code. Mybe that alone helps - if not, provide us these information.

Comment: How can i use LogCat to get relevant information? I added it as a window in eclipse but i get tons of information. Is there any way to sort the relevant information out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html) to check the emulator log for the crash message. If the message explains your problem fix it. If not add the message to your post and maybe we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LogCat for getting the reason of crash. it is available in the Eclipse, very left corner there is button and by clicking that you can see the option of the Logcat. when you launch the application it will show you all the logs. and when application crashes it will show upto the line level of crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logcat which you will find running your applications, and you can put `Log.e` or i v depending on what type of message you want to display. This way you can detect the exact error and where the application crashes.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {xml.android.test/xml.android.test.AndroidXMLActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
```

It means your activity `onCreate` method should call `super.onCreate()` (as its first line).